# Pass unknown object to method in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass an instance of a class to another object, but i can't get it to work.

I currently have this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void myFunc()
    {
        OtherClass bla = new OtherClass(this);
    }

    public void callback()
    {
        // code...
    }
}

class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass(Class<?> obj)
    {
        // do some stuff...

        // Call method from obj
        Method method = obj.getMethod("callback", SomeObject.getClass());
        method.invoke(obj, SomeObject);
    }
}
```

But now it gives me the following error:

> The constructor OtherClass(MyClass) is undefined

So it is expecting me to give the class name hardcode in the constructor. How can i make it a generic type, so that it accepts all classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
OtherClass bla = new OtherClass(this.getClass(), this);
```

And:

```
public OtherClass(Class<?> clazz, Object obj)
{
    // do some stuff...

    // Call method from obj
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("callback", SomeObject.getClass());
    method.invoke(obj, SomeObject);
}
```

**EDIT**

Reading my code, and your comment again, this can be done in even a simpler way, by passing only one parameter:

```
OtherClass bla = new OtherClass(this);
```

and:

```
public OtherClass(Object obj)
{
    Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
    // do some stuff...

    // Call method from obj
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("callback", SomeObject.getClass());
    method.invoke(obj, SomeObject);
}
```

Comment: NIce, you comment about: *`method.invoke` should be called on the object, not the class* really helped. It's working now the way i want.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an instance on a `MyClass` object, when the constructor expects an instance of a `Class` object. You could try;

```
OtherClass bla = new OtherClass(this.getClass());
```

Comment: This is only partially helpful, as `method.invoke` should be called on the object, not the class, so it has to be passed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public OtherClass(Class<? extends Object> obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public OtherClass(T obj)
```

instead.

Comment: Means! Any other changes required?

Comment: u need to cast it like this.class=(ParameterizedType)obj.getClass;

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is seriously flawed.  The signature of your constructor expects a class, but you're invoking a method on it.  Indicating it should be an object.

Also I don't see why you would do this; if you need to call a callback, just make an interface for it.

```
interface CallbackHaving{
  void callback();
}

class MyClass implements CallbackHaving
{
    public void myFunc()
    {
        OtherClass bla = new OtherClass(this);
    }

    public void callback()
    {
        // code...
    }
}

class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass(CallbackHaving obj)
    {
        // do some stuff...

        // Call method from obj
        obj.callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OtherClass constructor takes an object of type Class, but you're passing `this` to it, which is an object of type MyClass.  I think your constructor should be OtherClass(Object obj).